# Plotly x-axis formating

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, axis

Is there a way to the show annual dates on the xaxis of a python plotly plot. Right now it seems that there are too many ticks which form this dark bar at the bottom. Thanks in advance.[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrIqm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your dates are not in the right format. Try formatting them to a datetime object. For example using the pandas function `pandas.to_datetime`. [Documentation for pandas.to_datetime.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)